# Problem with simple FastLED sketch

Tags: arduino

I have a (well, so I thought) simple sketch for changing the brightness of an LED strip. There are two functions: one for increasing, and one for decreasing. Based on the `ledstatus` (1 is go down in brightness, and 0 is go up) it should go up and down.

But it only works once; when I set the `int ledstatus` to 1, it will do the `rampDOWN`, but it will not go back to `rampUP` even if the value of `ledstatus` is 0.

The 0 and 1 state will be done by a PIR eventually but somehow I can't get this to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, it'll be much appreciated.

The sketch:

```
#define FASTLED_INTERNAL                
#include "FastLED.h"                    
#define LED_PIN     7                  
#define NUM_LEDS    25                 
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];                  
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB                       

uint8_t val  ;
int valmin = 50;
int valmax = 250;
int ledstatus = 1;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  //FastLED.setBrightness(250);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (ledstatus == 0) {
    rampUP();
  }
  if (ledstatus == 1) {
    rampDOWN();
  }
}

void rampUP() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CHSV(32, 255, val);
  }

  EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(10) {
    if (valmin <= valmax) {
      val = valmin++;
    }
  }

  if (val == valmax) {
    //val = valmax;
    Serial.print(ledstatus); Serial.println(" = BACK TO HIGH BRIGTHNESS");
    ledstatus = 1;
    Serial.print(val); Serial.println(" = val up");
    Serial.print(ledstatus); Serial.println(" = NEW LEDSTATUS");
  }

  FastLED.show();
}

void rampDOWN() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CHSV(32, 255, val);
  }

  EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(10) {
    if (valmax >= valmin) {
      val = valmax--;
    }
  }

  if (val == valmin) {
    //val == valmin;
    Serial.print(ledstatus); Serial.println(" = BACK TO LOW BRIGTHNESS");
    ledstatus = 0;
    Serial.print(val); Serial.println(" = val down");
    Serial.print(ledstatus); Serial.println(" = NEW LEDSTATUS, so it must ramp up again...");
  }

  FastLED.show();
}
```

New working sketch:

````
#define FASTLED_INTERNAL
#include "FastLED.h"
#define LED_PIN     7
#define NUM_LEDS    25
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB

uint8_t val  ;
int valmin = 50;
int valmax = 250;
int ledstatus = 1;


void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

// Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (ledstatus == 0) {
    rampUP();
  }

  if (ledstatus == 1) {
    rampDOWN();
  }
}

void rampUP() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CHSV(32, 255, val);
  }


  EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(10) {
    if (valmin <= valmax) {
      val++;
    }
  }

  if (val == valmax) {
    //val = valmax;
    ledstatus = 1;
  }

  FastLED.show();
}



void rampDOWN() {

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CHSV(32, 255, val);
  }


  EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(10) {
    if (valmax >= valmin) {
      val--;
    }
  }

  if (val == valmin) {
    //val == valmin;
    ledstatus = 0;
  }

  FastLED.show();

}
```
````

Comment: (1) Hit the [edit] link. (2) Select your code. (3) Press the `{}` code formatting button. (4) Save.

Comment: OK, I did that before pasting the code and it only formatted the first line (when I pasted over 'enter code here'). Should have done that after I pasted it, I got it now, thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it. (1) Three ``` backticks before and after the code. (2) Four or more spaces at the start of each line. I suspect that you over-wrote the backticks.

Comment: you can also use ~~~ to format the code

Comment: After the call to rampDOWN(), notice that valmax is going to be 49. That seems wrong to me. Also, how does the library know about changes to val? You aren't telling it, you are simply changing a variable (val).  

I'm guessing you may need to put the setting of the leds[] array INSIDE the 10 ms loop, then call FastLED.show() each time after you set the leds array to a new val.

Comment: thanks @bob_monsen, I was indeed going down to 49 and measuring the wrong value in the Serial.print (had me fooled it went down to 50 but never got reset to 250).

I had my focus on the loop not switching based on the ledstatus instead of noticing the wrong value of val. I've changed some code and it's working perfectly now. Thanks or your help!